# What is a characterisation function

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am reading a paper: ["Probability of Backtest Overfitting"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2326253), and page 13 defines the relative frequency:

$$f(\lambda) = \sum_{c \in C_S} \frac{\chi_{\{\lambda\}} \left( \lambda_c\right)}{|\{C_S\}|}$$

the authors say that $\mathcal{X}$ is the characterization function. I would like to know what exactly that is since I have never come across that term before.

EDIT: I emailed the author of the paper, and according to him, $f(\lambda)$ is simply a PDF.

Comment: Did you mean $\chi_{\{\lambda\}} \left( \lambda_c\right)$ instead? (chi not X)

Comment: The characterization function of a set is a function returning $1$ for arguments in the set and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, sorry. So it is an indicator function?

Comment: So in this case, it would return $1$ if a given $\lambda_c$ is in the set of all the $\lambda$s? Is that what $\chi_{\{\lambda\}} $ denotes? The set of all $\lambda$s?

Comment: Hmmm, no. That does not make sense. $\lambda_c$ is a real value

Comment: In English we say: "characteristic function".  Perhaps that paper was translated (by the author, or by someone else) from another language? Now what that means depends on your branch of mathematics.  In probability it does not mean indicator function, but instead means sort of a Fourier transform...

Comment: @GEdgar, I am quite certain he did not mean to say characteristic function

Comment: In this case the characterization function did indeed refer to the characteristic function of a set, which is an indicator function, producing either 0 or 1.

Comment: I also doubt Marcos said that $f(\lambda)$ is a pdf; it is not very hard to tell from the form that $f(\lambda)$ is the cumulative distribution function for the r.v. $\lambda$, which, according to the paper, had a range of $(-\infty, \infty)$ and therefore was a continuous r.v.; this doesn't falsify the use of the relative frequency of $\lambda$ occurrence as the intermediary function to get the final probability: we feed the function with some continuous r.v., we do something inside the function (map the continuous logit value to a discrete integer number, in our example here).

Answer (score -1):

@i-squared-keep-it-real,

hello, I saw your edit but the fact $f(\lambda)$ is PDF still does not give a clue about what the $\chi$ is?

Should we solve the $\chi$ given the constraint $\int f(\lambda)d\lambda=1$ assuming $\chi$  is some type of function or should we fit something like Gaussian distribution to the frequency distribution ?

I mean without the $\chi$ how can I compute the $f(\lambda)$ to access to the POB?

Looking forward to an update!!

Thanks a lot!!

Sorry that I cannot comment...

Comment: hey, check out: https://github.com/vnazariy/agentBasedSimulation, overfit_basedOnBailey_** python notebook file, where it is all explained nicely